# Can anyone tell me step by step process on how to implement deeplinking concept in maui blazor application?

Tags: blazor, maui, blazor-webassembly, deep-linking

I have to make a POC on implementing a POC on how to implement a deeplinking concept in a mobile application. I dont know much about MAUI blazor and I didnt find any information on how to implement deeplinking in maui blazor. Can anyone explain step by step process on how I can implement deeplinking in a basic MAUI blazor project or share any beginner friendly resources or a sample git repository?

Thanks.

A working .net MAUI blazor application with deeplinking concept.

I tried using ChatGPT which didnt make much sense because I wasnt able to ask proper questions.
Few websites which are too complex for me.

Comment: To link into other apps: [Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?tabs=android). Note the steps that must be done on each target platform.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an open issue [Support deep linking into .NET MAUI Blazor apps](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3788) on the GitHub. Someone provided some methods to create the deeplinking on the different platforms. You can refer to this [thread](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3788#issuecomment-1297529268) for more information.